# Dealing with exporting 3rd party libraries while building a lib project

Tags: java, android, android-support-library

I am building an android library project. My library uses some third party libraries (like guava etc.). Now some other team needs to use this library that I am building.

My question is what should be done to the external libraries I am using while providing the library to the actual project .

Few options I thought are:

1. Export the 3rd party libraries.
   Issue: If I export these 3rd party libraries, then the project may face some issues like:
   a: If they are already using these 3rd party libs (with different version) then they will get duplication symbol errors. If they remove their 3rd party libs, then some classes may or may not exist. Also this would mean every time some application would need my library, it will be a hard integration nightmare.
2. Do not export the 3rd party libraries
   Issue: The application will get run time exceptions if the 3rd party lib classes used by my library do not exist in the 3rd party libs that the app has added.

Please tell what's the best way to go about this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is why where are so much build management tools out there. Use one of it. I am not sure what is the current suggested build tool of choice in classical Android development, but in non-Android project I would use Ant + Ivy or Maven. The approach is always the same: You define the 3rd party dependencies e.g. as compile or runtime dependency for your library project. Everytime you have a "usable" version of your lib, you publish it to a shared repository like a Nexus and that's it for you.
On the other side, your colleagues uses your lib as dependency. The build management tool will then handle this dependency like one of your 3rd party libs.

If you do not have any kind of build and source management infrastructure, now is the time to get one as your problem can't really be solved without such elementary tooling.